# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to achieve Swagger output filter

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

In ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with Swashbuckle / Swagger, I am accessing an Oracle database.

From the Oracle database, `BirthDate` is returned as a string (`VARCHAR`).

I have this `requestDto`:

```
namespace Transactions.Application.DTOs.Request
{
    public class RequestDto
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Without changing:

```
public string BirthDate { get; set; }
```

to

```
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

in the `Request` body of Swagger, I want the user to see:

```
{
    "firstName": "string",
    "lastName": "string",
    "birthDate": "YYYY-MM-DD"
}
```

Instead of :

```
{
    "firstName": "string",
    "lastName": "string",
    "birthDate": "string"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a description for user to reference without validation you could try below

```
        [DefaultValue("YYYY-MM-DD")]
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Test result
[image]